# Update nested state structure in Angular / ngrx reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I have a nested state structure that represents a time entry table. I store an array of `TimeEntryRow` objects, where each row object has it's own array of `TimeEntry` objects. Note that the objects store an index that represents their position in the table.

```
export interface TimeState {
    timeEntryRows?: TimeEntryRow[];
    ...
}

export class TimeEntryRow {
    rowIndex: number;
    timeEntries: TimeEntry[];
    ...
}

export class TimeEntry {
    cellIndex: number;
    hours: number;
    ...
}
```

I have a reducer that is attempting to update the hours of a single cell in the table, but I'm having some issues getting it to work. With the following action case, the state remains unchanged:

```
case timeEntryActions.HOURS_CHANGED_ACTION: {
    return {
        ...state,
        timeEntryRows: {
            ...state.timeEntryRows.map(row => {
                return row.rowIndex !== action.payload.rowIndex ? row : {
                    ...row,
                    timeEntries: {
                        ...row.timeEntries.map(te => {
                            return te.cellIndex !== action.payload.cellIndex ? te : {
                                ...te,
                                hours: action.payload.hours
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was accidentally setting my array properties `timeEntryRows` and `timeEntries` to objects, rather than arrays.

One more reason to avoid nested state as much as possible, as the reducers get longer and more complicated. Ended up using this [Redux resource](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#correct-approach:-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data) on how to properly update nested objects.

New code:

```
case timeEntryActions.HOURS_CHANGED_ACTION: {
    return {
        ...state,
        timeEntryRows: state.timeEntryRows.map(row => {
            return row.rowIndex !== action.payload.rowIndex ? row : {
                ...row,
                timeEntries: row.timeEntries.map(te => {
                    return te.cellIndex !== action.payload.cellIndex ? te : {
                        ...te,
                        hours: action.payload.hours
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```